# Capturing string literals optionally regex

Tags: regex

The output that I expect to get out of this is

1. SE 180, INDIVIDUAL STUDIES, 08/24/16, 12/12/16, R MAK
2. SE 180, INDIVIDUAL STUDIES, 08/24/16 ,12/12/16, H KATIRCIOGLU

However as you can see, sometimes because of how the data file was converted, an unexpected `(button)` appears in between the first two data fields.

Here is the regex that I came up with. I don't understand why it's not capturing. I was hopping a set of eyes would help me understand my error. I am still new to regex, however here is what I understand

In my case, in order to capture the string literal "(button)", I type `\(button\)`. For my data, the string literal always ends with a whitespace. And I want to make the whole group of data optional. Therefore I end up with, `(?:\(button\)\s?)?`.

**Regex Used**

https://regex101.com/r/88VDYN/1

```
([A-Z]+\s\S+)\s(?:\(button\)\s?)?([A-Z]+.+?)\s\d+\s\d+.+?(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)-(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s?(?:.*?([A-Z]\s[A-Z]+-*[A-Z]+))?\s
```

**Data Set**

```
SE 180 INDIVIDUAL STUDIES 92 49321 3 SUP 73 P 1/90 F 0730-1020 08/24/16-12/12/16 ENG 189 R MAK 
SE 180 
(button) 
INDIVIDUAL STUDIES 90 49320 3 SUP 73 P 0/50 MW 1500-1615 08/24/16-12/12/16 ENG 337 H KATIRCIOGLU
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test string actually has more than one whitespace character before and after the `(button)`. One is a newline, the other is a plain space.

You need to use `\s+` and `\s*` instead of just `\s` around your `(button)`:

```
([A-Z]+\s\S+)\s+(?:\(button\)\s*)?([A-Z]+.+?)\s\d+\s\d+.+?(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)-(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s?(?:.*?([A-Z]\s[A-Z]+-*[A-Z]+))?\s
               ^               ^
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/88VDYN/3)

Comment: Thank you sir! I am still fairly new to regex so I automatically assumed it was more of a syntax error on my part other then miss judgement of `\n` and whitespaces. Thank you again!

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `?:` in your pattern. That's what breaks it.

> `([A-Z]+\s\S+)\s(\(button\)\s?)?([A-Z]+.+?)\s\d+\s\d+.+?(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)-(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s?(?:.*?([A-Z]\s[A-Z]+-*[A-Z]+))?\s`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/heAj8F/1 I tried it and it still dosent work, also I had the `?:` in there because I didn't want the data in there to be captured. Is that not a good way to go about doing that?

Comment: I see your second test case has newlines before and after (button). Is that generally the case